# Working with Azure in Winrt with Rest API, trouble with signature

Tags: rest, azure, windows-runtime

I'm trying to work with azure storage in winrt. Since the azure storage client is not compatible with winrt I am trying to use azure's rest API. I am having a heck of a time getting the signature right and I could use another set of eyes to help me see where I'm going wrong.

Azure Account provides a name and key property, this method builds up the request right now simply listing all blobs.

'private async void BuildHTTPRequest(AzureAccount account)
    {
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient request = new HttpClient();

```
    request.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/", account.Name));

    // Always have to use UTC date/time
    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    string fmtStringToSign = "{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3:R}\n{4}{5}";

    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2011-08-18");

    string hdr = CanonicalizeHeaders(request.DefaultRequestHeaders);
    string authValue = string.Format(fmtStringToSign, "GET", "", "", "", hdr, "");
    byte[] signatureByteForm = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authValue);



    string hashKey = account.Key;

    MacAlgorithmProvider macAlgorithmProvider = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA256");
    BinaryStringEncoding encoding = BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8;
    var messageBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(authValue, encoding);
    IBuffer keyBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(hashKey, encoding);
    CryptographicKey hmacKey = macAlgorithmProvider.CreateKey(keyBuffer);
    IBuffer signedMessage = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, messageBuffer);

    string hashedString = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(signedMessage);

    String authHeader = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey",
    account.Name, hashedString);

    request.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

    // Send the request to the queue
    try
    {
        var test1 = request.GetAsync("?comp=list").Result;
        if (test1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {

        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex) { }


}
```

This should set the headers up for signing...

```
public string CanonicalizeHeaders(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders hdrCollection)
{
    StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();// Look for header names that start with "x-ms-"  // Then sort them in case-insensitive manner. 

    List<string> httpStorageHeaderNameArray = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> ht = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var key in hdrCollection)
    {
        if (key.Key.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("x-ms-", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            if (ht.ContainsKey(key.Key.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                ht[key.Key.ToLowerInvariant()] = string.Format("{0},{1}", ht[key.Key.ToLowerInvariant()],
                    hdrCollection.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == key.Key).ToString().Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                httpStorageHeaderNameArray.Add(key.Key.ToLowerInvariant());
                ht.Add(key.Key.ToLowerInvariant(),
                hdrCollection.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == key.Key).Value.FirstOrDefault().ToString().Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Trim());
            }
        }
    }

    httpStorageHeaderNameArray.Sort();// Now go through each header's values in the sorted order and append them to the canonicalized string.  
    foreach (string key in httpStorageHeaderNameArray)
    {
        retVal.AppendFormat("{0}:{1}\n", key.Trim(), ht[key]);
    }
    return retVal.ToString();
}
```

'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest version of storage client library supports WinRT. You can read more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/introducing-windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-for-net-and-windows-runtime.aspx. What I did was download the source code from Github: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net, opened the solution in VS 2012 and built `RT` project to get the necessary `winmd` files.

Coming to your problem, I believe you're running into this issue because you're passing an empty string for canonicalized resource string:

```
string authValue = string.Format(fmtStringToSign, "GET", "", "", "", hdr, "")
```

Please see this link for more details on creating canonicalized resource string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx.

Comment: You are officially my hero. I really wasn't sure what was supposed to be in the resource string. Really though the tip on winrt support is what I wanted :) its going to save a lot of work. Thanks!