# Authorization Header for Windows Azure Storage REST API from Windows Store App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

So I am just trying to list the tables in the storage account to test the authorization using the [Query Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179405.aspx) method. I tried using the SDK, but the SDK was trying to reference DLLs that aren't available in RT. Decided to try out the REST API. but am having trouble with the authentication from this spec http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179428.aspx

```
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Dictionary<string, string> headers = GetHeaders("/Tables");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(headers["Date"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedKey", headers["Authorization"]);
            const string url = "http://account-name.table.core.windows.net/Tables";
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(await client.GetStreamAsync(url));
            //
            // Do some stuff with the reader here
            //
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle exception
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetHeaders(string resource)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        headers["Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("R");
        headers["Authorization"] = GetAuthorizationHeader(resource, headers["Date"]);
        return headers;
    }

    public string GetAuthorizationHeader(string resource, string date)
    {
        const string key = PRIMARY_KEY;
        const string accountName = ACCOUNT_NAME;
        string signee = string.Join("\n", new List<string> { "GET", "", "", date, resource });
        // make the signature
        MacAlgorithmProvider hmac = MacAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm("HMAC_SHA256");
        IBuffer keyMaterial = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(key, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        CryptographicKey hmacKey = hmac.CreateKey(keyMaterial);
        IBuffer data = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(signee, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        IBuffer hash = CryptographicEngine.Sign(hmacKey, data);
        string signature = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hash);
        return string.Format("{0}:{1}", accountName, signature);
    }
```

Obviously I am missing something as I continue to get 403's. See any problems looking through this code?

Comment: Should mention that I tried different CanonizedResources than just /Tables, I also tried /accountname/Tables and a few others

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

There's a storage client library for Windows RT as well. Please take a look at my answer here: [Working with Azure in Winrt with Rest API, trouble with signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602918/working-with-azure-in-winrt-with-rest-api-trouble-with-signature/15603373#15603373).

Coming to your problem, can you try changing the following line of code:

```
headers["Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("R");
```

to

```
headers["Date"] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
```

and see if that helps.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed that you're using `CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary` to convert Base64 encoded key to bytes. Please try using `CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.decodefrombase64string.aspx) instead.

Comment: Good catch on the UtcNow line. Signature is still invalid, but that change needed to be made. As far as using the storage client library goes, I'm using .NET 4.5 and some of the dependencies for the library do not support 4.5, specifically System.Spatial which I why I'm trying to use the REST interface now

Comment: Updated my answer above. HTH.